# Only port 80 works for websites

Tags: iis, iis-7, network-programming, network-protocols, windows-server-2008-r2

I hosting a dedicated Server(win2008 Standart). IIS is installed. There are several Websites bound to different ports(eg SharepointServicesCentralAdministration to 17012).
Every website work well if is bound to port 80 but if i change the port i get timeout (connection via internet) - local it works well.
(Hardware and software firewall are down.)

For some additional test a c# TcpClient Instance is listening on port 12345. If i try connect via internet i get exception:
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:12345 - seems the same issue...

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: This sounds like a [SF] question to me.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely have port 80 forwarded to your machine from your internet bordering router/firewall.

You would need to have the other ports forwarded as well in your router/firewall for these other ports to work.

This also assumes you already opened the local firewall ports as you mentioned above, which is also required!

Comment: Please would you include more information on how to forward a port?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for other computers in the local subnet to connect? Probably only the local subnet is allowed. The setting needed for ip-restrictions has to be installed: http://www.hrzdata.com/node/46